# Why won't the origin stay with my object?

Tags: transforms, origin, axis

I want to make a face rig for my guy by saving the location, rotation, and scale of the lower jaw that way when I animate it to move it around, I can set it back to its original position in case I don't like it. However, when I was in "Object Mode" I went to "Set Origin" then selected "Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)" but when I clicked on "Apply" the origin is suddenly gone. Now every time I want to move my object I have to zoom out and find the pivot point which is annoying.[image]

Comment: Hello ! This is perfectly expected since applying the transforms means resetting the origin at (0, 0, 0). Maybe you only meant to apply the rotation and scale ? (ie uncheck "Location" in the panel in the lower left)

Comment: I unchecked apply locations, but when I move the jaw and pressed cleared location it still went back to world origins

Comment: It seems you don't really understand what object location means, I suggest you read up a bit more about it. Or explain what exactly you want to happen ? Maybe you want to parent the object to the head or something so its local transforms are at the origin ?